# Adding a textbox and a combobox in a webpage using Django CMS

Tags: django-cms

I've just started using Django CMS so my understanding of the tool is very limited, but I've been trying to do something that I assumed would be very simple, yet, I couldn't find a way of doing it.

I'm currently looking to add some textboxes and comboboxes on a webpage. I couldn't find these controls in the content section of the CMS. There are many choices like buttons, maps, videos, pictures, etc. but I didn't find textbox or combobox. How can I create these?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded the Aldryn package which seems to do the trick.